# Print an hourglass pattern

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I want to print the pattern in java and I have tried the following code. please guide me to solve my mistake.

```
import java.util.*;

class sp10
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        int i,j,n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value of n");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        for(i=n;i>=1;i--)
        {
            for(j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        
            for(j=1;j<=(2*i-1);j++)
            {
                if(j==1 || j==(2*i-1) ||i==n)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        } 
       
        for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(j=i;j<n;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(j=1;j<=(2*i-1);j++)
            {
                if(j==1 || j==(2*i-1)|| i==n)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        } 
    }
}
```

I am trying it in Java. Can you please guide me? It should print 5 stars in the first and the last line. Given below is the exact pattern

```
*****
*   *
 * *
  *
 * *
*   *
*****
```

Comment: *****
*   *
 * *
  *
 * *
*   *
*****   this is the exact pattern which i need

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: what consequence do you want your input n to have?

Comment: https://www.edureka.co/blog/30-pattern-programs-in-java/ -example number 11, 13, 14

Comment: what should be the input?

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's look at the pattern.

```
n = 5
*****
*   *
 * *
  *
 * *
*   *
*****
```

The first line and the last line is just print `*` `n` times.

```
private static void printTop(int n) {
    System.out.println("*".repeat(n));
}

private static void printBottom(int n) {
    printTop(n);
}
```

Though I wrote two methods here, you can just define one method like `printStar(int n)` and reuse it on the first and last line.

The real problem is to implement the middle part. Well, this still can be implemented in a relatively simple way. You just need to move `*` from column 0 to right and from `n-1` to left as the row increased.

```
private static void printMiddle(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int p = i;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j == p || j == n - 1 - p) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

`p` is the offset from column `0` to right or column `n-1` to left.

Now, you have everything. You can write the `main` method like the following:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter value of n");
    int n = sc.nextInt();

    printTop(n);
    printMiddle(n);
    printBottom(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, what you intended to do is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j, n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter value of n: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        for (i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (j = 1; j <= (2 * i - 1); j++) {
                if (j == 1 || j == (2 * i - 1) || (i == n && j % 2 == 1))
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 1; j <= (2 * i - 1); j++) {
                if (j == 1 || j == (2 * i - 1) || (i == n && j % 2 == 1))
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter value of n: 4
* * * *
 *   *
  * *
   *
  * *
 *   *
* * * *
```

However, if you insist that you need to print exactly what you have shown in the question, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j, n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter value of n: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        for (i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (j = 1; j <= (2 * i - 1); j++) {
                if ((j == 1 && i != n) || (j == (2 * i - 1) && i != n) || (j != 1 && i == n && j != (2 * i - 1)))
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 1; j <= (2 * i - 1); j++) {
                if ((j == 1 && i != n) || (j == (2 * i - 1) && i != n) || (j != 1 && i == n && j != (2 * i - 1)))
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter value of n: 4
 ***** 
 *   *
  * *
   *
  * *
 *   *
 *****
```

Comment: thanks everyone for guiding me and solving my query

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class sp10 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j, n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value of n");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < 2*n - 3; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (i = n-1; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (j = i; j <n; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            for (j = 1; j <= (2 * i - 1); j++) {
                if (j==1 || j == (2 * i - 1) || i == n ) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for (i = 2; i <= n-1; i++) {
            for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 1; j <= (2 * i - 1); j++) {
                if (j == 1 || j == (2 * i - 1) || i == n) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < 2*n - 3; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope is what you're looking for, because you question was a little bit difficult to understand...

With such solution the output is (for n = 4):

```
 *****
 *   *
  * *
   *
  * *
 *   *
 *****
```